# getActivity().getApplicationContext() java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragment

Доброго всем времени суток.

Не могу выловить ошибку в приложении, в эмуляторе Genymotion, на телефоне Nexus 5 работает превосходно, но ACRA от других пользователей постоянно сыпет отчетами об ошибке java.lang.NullPointerException.

Fragment.java

```
684 @Override
685 protected void onPostExecute(List<ObjectPlane> list) {
686     super.onPostExecute(list);

688     if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
689         getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
690             @Override
691             public void run() {
692                 progressDialogDismiss();
693                 setErrorTextAndButton();
694             }
695         });
696     } else {
697         if (adapter == null) {
698             adapter = new ObjectPlaneAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(editText.getText().toString());
                getQueryFromServer();
            } else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getQueryFromServer();
            }
        }
        if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        progressDialogDismiss();
    }
```

Вот что шлет ACRA:

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.koltsovo.www.koltsovo.Fragment.Fragment$parsingXML.onPostExecute(Fragment.java:698)
at ru.koltsovo.www.koltsovo.Fragment.Fragment$parsingXML.onPostExecute(Fragment.java:491)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: еще одно замечание - ```onPostExecute``` вызывается в ```UI``` потоке, поэтому ```getActivity().runOnUiThread()``` линшний

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит, если пользователь, например, вернулся на предыдущий фрагмент по бекстеку, или свернул приложение. Как только фрагмент детачится (`detach`), метод `getActivity()` начнет возвращать `null`, т. к. после этого фрагмент не принадлежит никакому `Activity`вы либо запоминайте предварительно `Activity` в переменную (это плохое решение, но простое), либо проверяйте, а приаттачен ли фрагмент к `Activity`, прежде, чем использовать эту `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметил @metalurgus, `getActivity()` возвращает `null` если фрагмент не прикреплён к активити. Т.е. задача завершилась тогда, когда фрагмент уже не отображается.

Засим добавьте проверку на это в `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<ObjectPlane> list) {
    super.onPostExecute(list);
    if(!isAdded())
    {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```